# "if" statement in python that checks if one variable is true but others are false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this line of code

```
if (SetNum == True) and SetChar and SetUp and SetLow == False:
   print("Your password contains", PassNum, "numbers")
```

When this is run nothing occurs, is there a way to have one part in an if statement true but others false?

Comment: Do you mean `if SetNum and not (SetChar or SetUp or SetLow)` ?

Comment: Do not use `== True` or `== False`, that should never be needed in a boolean test..

Comment: @khelwood this doesn't work in python 2.7; is it new functionality in 3.x?

Comment: @Vinny This is very basic logic. There is nothing new about it.

Comment: @khelwood I've put `,` instead of `or` between the values; sorry it perfectly works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `if variable` checks for truthness. This means you can write `if SetNum` and it would execute the same as `if SetNum == True`.

But that's just a more readable way; your issue is you misunderstand how `AND` works.

`if (SetNum == True) and SetChar and SetUp and SetLow == False:` this breaks to `SetNum == True` , and `SetChar`, which translates to truthness expression. So if it's True, it continues. next is `SetUp`, treated as same as `SetChar`. Basically you evaluate only the last item `SetLow == False`.

Consider this, which I believe is more readable

```
if SetNum:
    if not any(SetChar, SetUp, SetLow):
    ...
```

`any - Return True if bool(x) is True for any values x in the iterable.` It will validate each variable, and if they are all `False` it would return `False`. The `not` statement would substitute it to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this test in several ways

```
if (SetNum, SetChar, SetUp, SetLow) == (True, False, False, False):
   print("Your password contains", PassNum, "numbers")
```

or

```
if SetNum and not SetChar and not SetUp and not SetLow:
   print("Your password contains", PassNum, "numbers")
```